# Check math as you compose it

Tags: latex, math

I have no end of frustration trying to do math with pen and paper.  I can not seem to complete a page of working without making multiple mistakes.

I'm looking for something that will allow me to work on college-level math problems, checking my working as I go.

I've previously used LaTeX, but am open to learning a new system whether that involves sexps, APL, or something else.

I am hoping for something that, with practice, is at least as quick as pen and paper and can be converted to LaTeX.  And I'm hoping for something that is going to continue to improve (maybe Lean or some large language model?)

Comment: See this https://castel.dev/post/lecture-notes-1/ for the beginning - if you like it, there are two packages/implementations possible for Emacs, so your opinion first.

Comment: @Ian: That looks close to the setup I had previously in Vim. That is probably what I'll use unless anyone has a better idea. I am hoping to get away from LaTeX and towards something more computer-parseable. Specifically, I would like that when I write LHS = RHS, the system actually checks that they are equal.

Comment: I'm currently leaning towards Org-Babel with Julia (as [Julia looks closest to the typeset math](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGygK.jpg)) and then writing some Julia helper function to annotate the typeset output (e.g. put a little green checkmark above each equals sign that is correct). Any suggestions are still welcome!